# Change User licenses in enterprise edition or professional edition

Tags: user-management

Is there a possibility to change user licenses in enterprise or professional edtion in salesfroce?

And is there a possibility to user one user like "IT" user where in four other user's will use IT email address and salesforce could replicate each member of the IT based on the Record Type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I go to my org and into company information, it lists what licenses I have and has a button to buy more. That leads to https://store.salesforce.com/apex/home# where Salesforce says to contact sales  assistance to upgrade or renew your account.